# Read Blob from Database - using cUrl -> Rest API

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, blob

I think i have reached a dead end with this one... I am trying to retrieve Blob from database using cUrl (in php). The flow looks like following 
PHP (cUrL) -> 'url request' -> Rest API -> Database -> Rest -> array in PHP.

I have seen quite a few examples how to do it with direct SQL query but in what i am doing this it not the case. Below you can see how json data representation of the object in question.

```
"id": "f8fd460f-49a3-4f8b-91f9-5de8200b79e3",
    "insertedOn": "2012-12-01T18:57:17Z",
    "updatedOn": "2012-12-01T18:57:17Z",
    "identifier": "VirtuconAdapter@3238808399@2012-12-01T18:57:17.648+0000",
    "messageId": "0000c62a-f5bc-4900-8b46-7de4164abf09",
    "payloadSizeBytes": 0,
    "payload": "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",
    "metadata": {
        "source": "CyberdyneEngineering",
        "adapter_id": "VirtuconAdapter",
        "messageType": "T1000",
        "payloadIdentifier": "VirtuconAdapter@3238808399@2012-12-01T18:57:17.648+0000",
        "timestamp": "@2012-12-01T18:57:17.648+0000",
        "transactionRef": "REF1985300039",
        "hubItinerary": "CyberdyneAdapter",
        "destination": "VirtuconEngineering",
        "messageuniqueid": "0000c62a-f5bc-4900-8b46-7de4164abf09",
        "randomString": "@3238808399",
        "adpnextmlemarkersequence": "24",
        "documentTrackingId": "D0198556465",
        "routingDestination": "client.VirtuconAdapter.receive"
    }
```

So now the key would be to get this whole metadata array (which is blob)into something in php. hopefully i explained the problem well.

Thank for looking and help

Comment: I presume `payload` is the blob?

Comment: @MarcB Actually the metadata is blob. This json object is key - value pair map

Comment: please provide your PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you've stored that entire json object in SQL as your `blob`, and you've just pulled it out of the DB using PHP.

At that point, you'll have a string of json. What's stopping you from performing a `json_decode` method on that string?

Comment: Yes i have realised that yesterday that i could just do json_decode(foo, true) and that will return me array. But anyway thx for answer :)